# 1072 "user_id does not exist in table." any way to fix?

Tags: sql, mysql

So I was creating a database for the first time but my user_id does not exist? How can I fix this? My code was:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(30),
    comment_text TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,
    users_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Create a comment table but user_id does not exist.

Comment: Is it a typo? You are creating `users_id` and then primary and foreign key is `user_id`.

Comment: Also why is the primary key `user_id` and not `id`?

Comment: you should also know that a column that is defined as `"auto-increment"` **must** be defined as a key

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues

- PRIMARY KEY should be id to refer comment id
- Use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead of CURRENT_TIME to keep data with time
- users_id cannot be NOT NULL in creating relation
- possible typo users_id instead of user_id in relation many to one
- you probably mean CASCADE instead of SET NULL on relation in this case if user will be delated from users table it will delete all comments from this user

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(30),
    comment_text TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    user_id INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```